# ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need your help. I am having issue with this code. All I want to do is to apply link to each of the list item in the controller. When I click on a single link it takes me to a new page entirely, displaying the item id in the URL.

Please find attached the code below.

```
        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "John Smith"},              
            new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Mary Williams"}
        };

        var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel
        {
            customers = customers
        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you can do is to just add a new field to the Customer class called Link so it would look like:

```
public Class
{
   public string Link => "linkToResource/" + Id;

   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your .cshtml page, you can just create links using the pure `HTML` like this:

```
@foreach (var customer in Customers)
{  
  <a href="someUrl/@customer.Link"> customer @customer.Id</a>
}
```

Or the second option I see is to e.g. create links to the detail page of each customer, so in your .cshtml page, you can create links using the Html.ActionLink looping thru all the Customers

```
@foreach (var customer in Customers)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("User" + customer.Id,"Details","Customer",new {id = customer.Id})
}
```